# How to get number of affected rows from a mssql query in php pdo

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

I am changing my php project from using mysql to mssql.
when i use 
`if ($query->rowCount() == 0) {` with mysql it works well but with mssql i get a negative value which isnt correct.
So i tried to use `$count = count($query->fetchAll());` with mssql which gives me a positive value similar to when using mysql but i get an error 
I am using [Php drivers for sql server](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases)

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: There are no more rows in the active result set. Since this result set is not scrollable, no more data may be retrieved.

Need some help with this issue

Comment: Why have you tagged MySQL and SQL Server? Which RDBMS are you really using?

Comment: Which driver do you use to connect to MS SQL Server?

Comment: @Zhorov using php drivers for sql server

Comment: @Larnu sorry for that, i use both. am just trying to change from mysql to mssql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is clear about [PDOStatement::rowCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/pdostatement-rowcount?view=sql-server-2017).

> Returns the number of rows added, deleted, or changed. If the last SQL
>   statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT
>   statement, a PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY cursor returns -1. A
>   PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL ABLE cursor returns the number of rows in the
>   result set.

If you want to use `rowCount()` for `SELECT` statements, you need to use `PDO::CURSOR_SCROLLABLE`:

```
<?php  
#
$server = "server\instance,port";  
$dbname = "database";
$uid = "uid";  
$pwd = "pwd";  

# Connection
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server ; Database = $dbname", $uid, $pwd);  

# SELECT statement
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table1";  
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));  
$stmt->execute();  
echo $stmt->rowCount();  

# End
$stmt = null;
$conn = null;
?>
```

When you use `$count = count($query->fetchAll());` your result set is already fetched after `$query->fetchAll()` call. If you try to call `PDOStatement::fetch` or `PDOStatement::fetchAll` methods, you'll get this error.

Try the next approach:

```
<?php

...
$result = $query->fetchAll(); 
$count = count($result);
foreach ($result as $row) {

}
...

?>
```